# How to move suddenly a few records forward, or backward using java ListIterator

Tags: java, string, list, iterator

How to move a few records forward, or backward. Then return to the place and go on normally in a loop. I want to go back during iteration, e.g. 2 records back and delete something, then return and go further.

```
item 1
item 2 <- #2 STEP: go back 2 records and delete, 
item 3
item 4 <- #1 STEP: iterator, #3 STEP: return to the iterator and go further
item 5
item 6
item 7
```

All records are in `List<String>`

Comment: Depends on what implementation of `List` you are using... Is it an `ArrayList`, a `LinkedList` or anything else? Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Since you're already using `ListIterator` what's the problem with calling `previous()` and `next()` as often as needed to navigate the list? If you add/delete elements you'd need to adjust the number of calls but otherwise it shouldn't be too hard. What you can't/shouldn't do is modify the list without the iterator while you're using it ... you'll most likely get a `ConcurrentModificationException` since you'll confuse the iterator.

Comment: I am using a LinkedList, so far I tried with iterators, and foreach loop but I have a `ConcurrentModificationException` exception.